# Topological invariance of periodic cyclic homology of stacks

Tags: algebraic-stacks, derived-algebraic-geometry, cyclic-homology

Goodwillie proved (in *Cyclic homology, derivations, and the free loopspace*) that the periodic cyclic homology of a connective dg algebra is that of its reduced classical ring.  Preygel proved (in *Ind-coherent sheaves on loop spaces*) that the periodic cyclic homology of the category of coherent sheaves on a derived algebraic space and the periodic cyclic homology of D-modules on that space are Tate equivalent, which should yield a corollary that the periodic cyclic homology of a derived algebraic space is that of its classical reduced algebraic space.

These results suggest that periodic cyclic homology has a ``topological invariance.''  My question is whether this such results are known more generally for coherent sheaves on quotient stacks.

I've tried using the above results with little success.  One might try, on stacks with a good set of generators and the resolution property, to use Goodwillie's result, but it seems to not generalize to coconnective dg algebras (e.g. $\text{Ext}$ algebras on generators).  One might also try to generalize Preygel's result, but this would say something about formal loop spaces rather than loop spaces (the latter help compute Hochschild homology of stacks).